# высокое подчеркиванние

Tags: css, html5

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать такое подчёркивание, чтобы подчеркивался низ ли высотой 120рх

[[image: 120рх1]

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
  --font-size: 2rem;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  height: 120px;
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: var(--font-size);
  padding: calc(60px - var(--font-size) / 2) 0;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
}

li:hover,
li:focus {
  border-bottom-color: rgb(228, 6, 6);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li tabindex="0">text</li>
  <li tabindex="0">text</li>
  <li tabindex="0">text</li>
  <li tabindex="0">text</li>
  <li tabindex="0">text</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если я вас правильно поняла, то так. И я бы не задавала жестко высоту, либо min-height, а лучше padding.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
  --font-size: 2rem;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: var(--font-size);
  padding-bottom: 120px;
}

li:hover,
li:focus {
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(228, 6, 6);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li tabindex="0">text</li>
  <li tabindex="0">text</li>
  <li tabindex="0">text</li>
  <li tabindex="0">text</li>
  <li tabindex="0">text</li>
</ul>
```